# How to solve windows file/folder permission bug

Tags: file, permissions, directory, windows-server-2003

I have a windows server with a folder that has more than 200.000 pictures in it with total 
~120GB capacity. Also this folder's parent folder got some different security permissions than all other children folders.

My problem is when i deleted a permission from one of my users it started to act like crazy.
I mean it is really crazy cause at the end i saw that some of my files has no security permission at all!

I tried to add same permissions back to those files by their folder permission settings but it keeps giving "Access denied!" error. I also tried to add permissions as Administrator but even Administrator dont have a permission to do anything on those files! I'm pretty sure this is some sort of windows bug. I have to find a way trough this. I cant copy or change any of these files.

Now my files has no security or permission entry and as administrator i'm not eligible enough to add or view any permission settings.. so how can i solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried taking ownership of the affected files?

- On the "Security" tab, click the "Advanced" button at the bottom;
- Select the "Owner" tab and click "Edit";
- Select either your account or the Administrators group, and click "OK";
- Keep clicking "OK" until you've closed the properties dialog;
- Open the properties dialog again and try to change the permissions;

If you want to do this from the command-line:

```
takeown /f "Your File/Folder Name Here" /r /d y
icacls "Your File/Folder Name Here" /grant administrators:F /t
```

Comment: I got ERROR: Access is denied. when I tried this from the command line and there is no button in explorer.